Android Virtual A/B OTA - Post Reboot merge failed during update_engine snapshot merge
So we have been trying Android OTA and AFAIK starting with Android 12 (which is what I am using now), android uses concept of virtual A/B where the super partition is dynamically sized during OTA.
And to achieve this seamless update concept on Virtual A/B, android relies on device-mapper and dm-snapshot modules (linux kernel).
https://source.android.com/docs/core/ota/virtual_ab#dm-snapshot-overview
now to the actual issue we have been chasing -
During OTA, android update_engine uses dm-snapshot to take the snapshot of the base and cow partition and downloads the new package onto it. Once OTA is done, system goes for reboot and android initially try to boot into the snapshot to confirm new update didnt really mess up the system and waits for bootmarksuccessfull() flag being set.
Once it confirms that boot is successfull, update_engine initiates the merge process to bring snapshot into orginal partition.
Issue: During the merge process, update_engine detects that there is a merge failure in the snapshot (written by device-mapper driver) and logs the message saying the merge is failed and device corrupted. When I closely looked at it, merge failure is coming from underneath device-mapper driver
Device-mapper logs:

device-mapper: snapshots: Read error: shutting down merge.

Android update_engine logs:
Initiating merge for 3 snapshots
 update_engine: CheckTargetMergeState for vendor_a returned: 5
 update_engine: CheckMergeState for snapshots returned: 6
 update_engine: ProcessUpdateState handling state: 6
 update_engine: Merge could not be completed and will be marked as failed.
 update_engine: [ERROR:cleanup_previous_update_action.cc(357)] Merge failed. Device may be corrupted.
 update_engine: [INFO:cleanup_previous_update_action.cc(134)] Stopping/suspending/completing 
 update_engine: [INFO:cleanup_previous_update_action.cc(522)] Reporting merge stats: MergeFailed in 20057ms (resumed 0 times), using 0 bytes of COW image.
 update_engine: [INFO:cleanup_previous_update_action.cc(134)] Stopping/suspending/completing CleanupPreviousUpdateAction
 update_engine: [INFO:action_processor.cc(116)] ActionProcessor: finished last action CleanupPreviousUpdateAction with code ErrorCode::kDeviceCorrupted

I have skimmed thru  update_engine snapshot with bunch of logs and still have no clue on what might be going on especially at system level?
If it helps, android is running as guest VM so not sure if any underneath virtio or some sort of flush is coming in between?
any insights would be appreciated...
